# Psycopg2 is not working

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to Postgres database using psycopg2 in a Django app but I am unable to connect. It is not throwing any exception whatsoever. I am not even able to debug it due to lack of exception throwing.

I used -

```
db_settings = settings.DATABASES['default']
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=" + db_settings['NAME'] + 
" user=" db_settings['USER'] + " host=" +
db_settings['HOST'] + " password=" + db_settings['PASSWORD'])

cur = conn.cursor()
```

Here settings is the setting file in my Django app. Any suggestions how can I move forward and debug it so that I can find what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using django, then why not let django handle the database?

Answer (score 0):

to debug... open a django shell:

```
./manage.py shell
```

then in the console, import all you need and test

```
import psycopg2
from django.conf import settings
# have fun
```

or use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) in your code

Hope this helps